# thread not working as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to test something with the `threading` module and I'm really confused on why this is not working. I'm also using windows 8, but I tried this exact code on a linux virtual machine and get the same results, am I using the thread wrong?

```
import threading


# test.py 
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()
    def connect(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.loop, daemon=True).start()

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            print("works?")
Test()
```

so if I run this in IDLE it works fine but as soon as I try it with the command prompt it prints "works?" one time then freezes and I can't send the kill command to it either.

If I remove `threading.Thread(target=self.loop, daemon=True).start()` and replace it with `self.loop()` it works fine in the command prompt. Why is using `threading.Thread(target=self.loop, daemon=True)` not working?

Any advice on how to get it to work in command prompt?

Comment: This seems like it has something to do with bound methods vs unbound methods, but I'm not smart enough to figure it out. Reading the code it doesn't seem like it should make a difference, since `loop` doesn't do anything with the `Test` instance it was invoked from.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should just be building a `Thread` rather than building a class that makes a `Thread` use one of its methods!

```
class Test(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwds)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("works?")
t = Test()
t.start()
```

As for why your code works in IDLE but not at the command line, I'm afraid I don't know. If a more experienced Python-er wants to edit this answer with a more complete explanation, they should certainly feel free to!

Comment: I see a similar problem in both Linux and Windows. It hangs with `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"works?\n")`, but not with `sys.stdout.buffer.raw.write(b"works?\n")`. This implicates the `BufferedWriter`. Inserting a small sleep in the loop like `time.sleep(0.5)` also works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, all my active threads were daemonic(need them to be so I can kill them with ctrl c on windows) so as soon as the task was finished they exited. Python probably counts the IDLE shell as a non daemonic thread, so it was able to continue running but the command prompt or terminal do not count as threads so it exited immediately, here is a fix.

```
import threading

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()
    def connect(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.loop, daemon=True).start()

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            print("works?")
NEEDS_STARTED = True
while True:
    if NEEDS_STARTED:
        Test()
```

Or alternatively

```
import threading

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()
    def connect(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.loop).start()

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            print("works?")
```

Thanks for the suggestions and comments though. If anyone can explain why it didn't work with a better explanation incase someone has a similar issue.